# Unable to specify the thrown error by the function to be tested in mocha nodejs. expect.to.throw (Error) not working

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

This is function for which I have written test cases.

```
exports.sendOTPParser = event => {
console.log('sendOTPParser');
event = event || {};
try {
const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
const phoneNumber = body.phonenumber;
if (typeof phoneNumber !== 'string') {
  throw new Error('MalformedRequest');
}
event.phoneNumber = body.phonenumber;
return event;
} catch (error) {
console.log('Error in isEmailUniqueParser: %s', error.message);
throw new Error('MalformedRequest');
}

}
```

And this is the mocha code to test the given function. But, it is not catching error. Whats wrong??

```
var file = require('../src/auth/eventParsers');

var expect    = require('chai').expect;

describe('sendOTPParserTest', function(){

var event1 =  {"body": '{"phonenumber": 1234}'};
var event2 =  {"body": '{"phonenumber": "1234"}'};

// event2.body.phonenumber = '12345';
// event1.body.phonenumber = 12345;

it('returnTest', function(){
var result1 = file.sendOTPParser(event1);
// var result2 = file.sendOTPParser(event2);                expect(result2.phoneNumber).to.equal(JSON.parse(event2.body).phonenumber);
    expect(result1).to.throw(Error);

});

});
```

output:

```
bash-3.2$ mocha sendOTPParserTest.js

sendOTPParserTest
sendOTPParser
 Error in isEmailUniqueParser: MalformedRequest
 1) returnTest


   0 passing (14ms)
   1 failing

   1) sendOTPParserTest returnTest:
    Error: MalformedRequest
    at
```

Comment: output:bash-3.2$ mocha sendOTPParserTest.js


  sendOTPParserTest
sendOTPParser
Error in isEmailUniqueParser: MalformedRequest
    1) returnTest


  0 passing (14ms)
  1 failing

  1) sendOTPParserTest returnTest:
     Error: MalformedRequest
      at Object.exports.userCreateEventParser.exports.sendOTPParser.event [as sendOTPParser] (/Users/akshayrelfor/Documents/curber-dir/src/auth/eventParsers.js:40:11)
      at Context.<anonymous> (sendOTPParserTest.js:15:24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chai's [`throw`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) assertion requires a *function*, not a function *result*.

To make it work, you can use something like this:

```
it('returnTest', function() {
  expect(() => file.sendOTPParser(event1)).to.throw(Error);
});
```

Comment: I have tested it , still not working. I have even tried by nesting the result inside the anonymous function. But, it is still giving the problem.

Comment: It works just fine for me. To be clear, you have to remove the line `var result1 = ...` right above the `expect()`. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, it is working. I forget to remove that line